# How to use CardIO and Paypal-iOS-sdk in the same project (Duplicate Symbols)

Tags: ios, xcode, paypal, sdk

The static library included with the Paypal-iOS-SDK includes CardIO - my app already includes CardIO separately to process payments via a different gateway. I want to accept Paypal payments in the app as well but including both SDKs leads to duplicate symbols.

This is something I believe should be on PayPal's radar as I would've thought it would've been a common situation.

Is there any way to get around this limitation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question here the answer is kind of obvious:

```
-Delete libCardIO.a from the CardIO SDK directory (but leave the headers)
-remove "-lCardIO" from Other Linker Flags
```

Comment: Well done! I have exactly the same problem but somehow i can't find the libCardIO.a in the current SDK lib(version 3.1.4). The folder structure is "/io/card/payment/". Can you please give me a hint?